# How can I debug the Sign In With Google (GSI) library?

Tags: debugging, google-signin, log-level

I'm using the [Sign In With Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference) library (also known as GSI). It's not working as I expect, and I want to debug its behavior. How can I set the log level, or otherwise understand its behavior?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `log_level` option to `'debug'`, like so:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  google.accounts.id.initialize({
    log_level: 'debug',  // THE ALL-IMPORTANT SETTING
    client_id: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID',
    callback: handleCredentialResponse
  });
  google.accounts.id.prompt();
};
```

You will now get explanations in the console. For example, if `prompt()` does cause the prompt to appear, you will see an explanation like:

```
[GSI_LOGGER]: User has closed One Tap before. Still in the cool down period.
[GSI_LOGGER]: Prompt will not be displayed
```

This setting is undocumented by Google (!), but extraordinarily helpful.